# Python numpy.savetxt - no such file or directory, although path is correct

Tags: python, numpy

Found no solution here on stackoverflow yet. In the threads I read, where this problem is considered, the problem was triggered by a wrong path. But in my case, the path should be correct, since I copied it to the windows navigation line and it worked.

The error message looks as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\micha\Dropbox\10. Semester\Fabios_error_bound\python_new_pc\feb_error_calculation_and_plotting\feb_error_calculation_and_plotting\feb_error_calculation_and_plotting.py", line 99, in <module>
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(working_directory,error_folder,current_name.replace('.txt','')+'error_pop11.txt'),error_pop11, fmt='%20.14f')
  File "C:\Python27amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1194, in savetxt
    fh = open(fname, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\micha\\Dropbox\\10. Semester\\Fabios_error_bound\\python_new_pc\\feb_error_calculation_and_plotting\\feb_error_calculation_and_plotting\\error2\\ses_pop_site_eb__ohmic_lam50_gam100_T100_SD_ohmic_lam50_gam100_T100_angle39_Chl658_Egap0_J100_M2_K0_L8error_pop11.txt'
```

Furthermore, it works on my PC, but not on my notebook. In both cases I'm using Visual Studio with Python 3.5 and 3.6, respectively (with 2.7 it also doesn't work on my Notebook).

Does anybody has a clue?

Comment: Try to change `\\`` to `/` in path name

Comment: Many thanks for this, but the path is generated automatically by using 'os.path.join', no? Also tried it, but didn't work.

Comment: Check this `...error2\\\ses_po...`.

Comment: Sorry for this. It occured as I first erased some part of the path and inserted it afterwards in the post. So, everywhere are double backslashes '\\'. Fixed it in the post now.

Comment: Does the subdirectory `error2` exist?

Comment: Yes it does. As written, I copied the path  "os.path.join(***)" and inserted it into the windows navigation line and it worked.